# What are the advantages of backing up on an external disk instead of the deja-dup in the home directory?

Tags: backup, compression

I've been advised to do so in a Youtube video, so I'd like to know. Also, if the backup application uses any sort of compression, how much would it be reduced to?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If your hard drive fails, and you have backed up to that same hard drive, you will lose all your data.  Backing up to an external device allows for that type of failure to occur without you losing your data.

Deja-dup does use compression, but I am not sure that the reduction amount is predictable.  It depends on what is being compressed.